# Can't seem to change the bg or fg color with the tkinter library

Tags: python, tkinter

I just started playing around with tkinter and while trying to change the colors of the widgets i keep getting this error `_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-fg": must be -column, -columnspan, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky` i cant seem to find the solution to it, tried to use the turtle library to change the color as well but cant seem to get it working I'm relatively new so help would be appreciated

I'm using pyhton 3.10

```
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
lbl =  Label(root, text='Hello!', font=("Arial Bold", 50))
btn = Button(root, text='Button 1')


frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frm.grid()
root.geometry=('350x200+20+30')
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0, fg= 'blue')
btn.grid(column=1, row=0)
root.title('Test One Lets see if this works')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're passing the `fg` parameter to the `grid` method, which is the wrong place to put it.

Answer (score 2):

In tkinter, you first create a widget and then use one of the geometry managers (`grid`, `pack`, `place`) to display it on screen.

All the parameters which make logical sense even if you isolate the widget are given when you create the widget.
Eg: font, bg, fg, bd, highlightthickness, text

On the other hand, parameters that handle the positioning of the widget on screen are given using a geometry manager.
Eg: row, column, padx, pady, ipadx, ipady, sticky, expand, rowspan, columnspan

Now, coming to your problem, you need to give `fg` when you create `lbl` as follows:

```
lbl =  Label(root, text='Hello!', font=("Arial Bold", 50), fg = "blue")
```